# Responsive design div not expanding with screen width

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have set up a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/25d8ejkf/1/

I have a simple article listing page where i need to list article in a matrix of N x 2 rows

i want design of two columns to be maintained till screen size is 680 pixel and then it should show single image per row.

At present it switch from two columns to one column when screen is 768px.

How can i make div auto adjust width while maintaining the design.

I tried  css `width:auto; height:auto; max-width:310px; max-height:207px;` but it i snot working

```
.news
{
    float:left;
    max-width:310px;
    max-height:207px;
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    background-color:Fuchsia;
    margin-right:31px;
    margin-bottom:31px;  
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="news-wrapper">
    <div class="news">
        <div class="news-date"><span class="news-day"></span><span class="news-month"></span><span class="news-year"></span></div>
        <div class="news-image"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/310x207/000/ccc" /></div>
        <div class="news-title"><span class="news-title-h1"></span></div>
    </div>

    <div class="news">
        <div class="news-date"><span class="news-day"></span><span class="news-month"></span><span class="news-year"></span></div>
        <div class="news-image"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/310x207/000/ccc" /></div>
        <div class="news-title"><span class="news-title-h1"></span></div>
    </div>

    <div class="news">
        <div class="news-date"><span class="news-day"></span><span class="news-month"></span><span class="news-year"></span></div>
        <div class="news-image"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/310x207/000/ccc" /></div>
        <div class="news-title"><span class="news-title-h1"></span></div>
    </div>

    <div class="news">
        <div class="news-date"><span class="news-day"></span><span class="news-month"></span><span class="news-year"></span></div>
        <div class="news-image"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/310x207/000/ccc" /></div>
        <div class="news-title"><span class="news-title-h1"></span></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

UPDATE:

To explain more i am adding two sample to make it more clear about the design

[image]

[image]

Comment: try http://jsfiddle.net/25d8ejkf/5/

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Is this what you are trying to do? http://jsfiddle.net/25d8ejkf/6/

Comment: @AlexWilson, I am not sure if this is right it is not reducing the width of the div with class `news`..

Comment: I think you should use `display: flex` instead of `float: left;`. Look at this guide http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

You probobly want to use percentes to do that.

```
width:100%;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
@media (max-width: 768px){
    .news{
        width:100%;
        max-width: none;
     }
}
```

Hope this solves the issue. :)